# How to properly save each large chunk of data as a pandas dataframe and concatenate them with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bigdata, large-data

I have a dataframe that has over 400K rows and several hundred columns that I have decided to read in with chunks because it does not fit into Memory and gives me MemoryError.

I have managed to read it in in chunks like this:

```
x = pd.read_csv('Training.csv', chunksize=10000)
```

and afterwards I can get each of the chunks by doing this:

```
a = x.get_chunk()
b = x.get_chunk()
```

etc etc keep doing this over 40 times which is obviously slow and bad programming practice.

When I try doing the following in an attempt to create a loop that can save each chunk into a dataframe and somehow concatenate them:

```
for x in pd.read_csv('Training.csv', chunksize=500):
    x.get_chunk()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_chunk'
```

What is the easiest way I can read in my file and concatenate all my chunks during the import?

Also, how do I do further manipulation on my dataset to avoid memory error issues (particularly, imputing null values, standardizing/normalizing the dataframe, and then running machine learning models on it using scikit learn?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` does not return an iterable, so looping over it does not make sense. I do not know enough about `pandas` or the chunk reader methods, but depending on what `get_chunk` does when you request the next chunk after the last you'd need an `if` or `try`/`except` statement to check whether the iteration should stop. Obviously you'd get the same memory problems if you just concatenate all the chunks into one big DataFrame. The chunk method is for cases where you do your processing on your smaller, chunks, i.e. the chunks have no inter-dependencies.

Comment: `x` is already a `DataFrame`, so you can just add it to a list and then concatenate them all at the end. But if you can fit the entire file into memory to begin with, since you are going to concatenate at the end, don't read it in chunks. That's really meant for when you can't fit the entire thing into memory and need to process individual parts one at a time.

Comment: Off topic, that's amazing, PhD in Physics from Yale:)) I can't fit it into memory, that's why I am doing this. And how would I do what you suggested?

Comment: Just remove the `.get_chunk`. In your loop `x` is the `DataFrame` of 5000 rows, so just process it as you would the larger file.

Comment: Try this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa with the `chunksize` parameter specified, pandas does return an iterable object `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader`

Comment: question, when I try to do what I think you suggested above like this: data = []

for x in pd.read_csv('Training.csv', chunksize=500):
    data.append(x)

Comment: and then I just do pd.DataFrame(data) to convert it to a dataframe it outputs me 16 rows (generated by 16 chunks that I have) that are 1 row and 1 column each of the same thing: Unamed: 0 Account Owner

Comment: In that case, `data` is a list of `DataFrames`, so you want to do `df = pd.concat(data)` to join the list into a single `DataFrame`.

Comment: oh wow, didn't know there was such as thing as a list of dataframes. ok, this accomplished what I wanted it to for now, not sure how it will work on other processes, including building a model using scikit-learn, I have never done it on anything that couldn't fit into memory before. I can upvote your answer if you want to put one.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify chunksize in a call to pandas.read_csv you get back a pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object rather than a DataFrame. Try this to go through the chunks:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('Training.csv',chunksize=500)
for chunk in reader:
    print(type(chunk)) # chunk is a dataframe
```

Or grab all the chunks (which probably won't solve your problem!):

```
reader = pd.read_csv('Training.csv',chunksize=500)
chunks = [chunk for chunk in reader] # list of DataFrames
```

Depending on what is in your dataset a great way of reducing memory use is to identify columns that can be converted to categorical data. Any column where the number of distinct values is much lower than the number of rows is a candidate for this. Suppose a column contains some sort of status with limited values (e.g. 'Open','Closed','On hold') do this:

```
chunk['Status'] = chunk.assign(Status=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['Status']))
```

This will now store just an integer for each row and the DataFrame will hold a mapping (e.g 0 = 'Open', 1 = 'Closed etc. etc.)

You should also look at whether or not any of your data columns are redundant (they effectively contain the same information) - if any are then delete them. I've seen spreadsheets containing dates where people have generated columns for year, week, day as they find it easier to work with. Get rid of them!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess I don't fully follow what you want me to get out of this. What is the purpose of checking the type? I wrote your code and it is showing it as a pandas dataframe (I mean using your first code section). How exactly would I use it to get it back into 1 chunk though? Most of my columns, almost all actually, are actually categorical variables that I get_dummies() earlier from 1 column aka one-hot encoded.

Comment: I only put the type statement there to demonstrate how you get the DataFrame object. Do whatever DataFrame stuff you want with chunk, e.g. chunk.head() ...